# Read multiplae lines at one time in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm developing a program in which the user shall enter some numbers which should be read.

Until now, the user has to enter each number individually:

```
for(int i=0;i<lng;i++){
line[i]=scanner.nextLine();
}
```

How can I optimize the code so that the user can insert a whole block of numbers, and then the ith Line of this block is read as line[i-1]?

Comment: Enter all numbers on one line separated by spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int lng = 10;
    String [] line = new String[lng];
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int i=0;i<lng;i++){
        line[i]=scanner.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(line));
}
```

enter 10 names or any string, to enter correctly, enter first name click enter, enter second click enter and so one.

to do same with numbers see next code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int lng = 10;
    int [] line = new int[lng];
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int i=0;i<lng;i++){
        line[i]=scanner.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(line));
}
```

when 10 input is stored in array system will terminate and print array in console.